# Unnecessary wrapping of text in crystal report

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports

I am facing a very strange problem while working with crystal report in vs 2012. I am using a formula field to create a string and displaying that field in my report.

But the problem is that while executing this report, the text in that field automatically wraps before ending of the current line.

I've absolutely no idea what am i doing wrong.

Refer to the attached snapshot.
The text in line "1" is wrapping way before line ending.

Code that I am using in the formula field:

```
'आपको उकत आवस जरिये लॉटरी/दिनांक '+CStr({LottaryAllotment_Detail.AllotmentDate},"dd MM yyyy")+' को रुपये '+CStr({Master_Lottary.TotalAmount})+' मे आंवटन किया गया है।'+' '+ 'आप द्धारा आवास गृह की अमानत व पूर्व ग्रहण राशी रु '+ cstr({Master_Lottary.EarnestMoney})+' जमा करा दी है एवं शेष राशी किश्तो में जमा करने बाबत  मांग पत्र मांग पत्र जारी किया जा चुका है।'
```

[image: The text in line "1" is wrapping way before line ending.]

Comment: Are you certain that the data does not contain a CR and/or LF character?

Comment: Yes, The data does not contains any newline character. For your reference, I am sharing the code in the formula field that I am using.

Comment: This won't help, but I copied and pasted the code into Crystal XI (changing the `CStr({field})` entries to static text).  It didn't break for me when I had "Can grow" off (except for not seeing all of the text), and when I had can grow on, I just got the you-don't-have-this-language-installed boxes instead of the Hindi characters.

Comment: Thats pretty strange. But I managed to get this to work by setting the font property of the field to "Mangal" which is shipped with Microsoft OS.

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem has to do with the character encoding since you use Hindi language. Try to set the font to Arial Unicode MS this will solve it.